# finding the minmum integer and its adress in mips

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, min, minimum

I am learning assembly language and i`m using mips.
My code work fine but doesn't stop when the array is finished

This is my code
can you tell me what is the correct condition ( in B: )  to stop the program and go to exist ?

```
.data
A: .word 12,31,5,72,4
E: .byte

.text 

la $t1,A        # t1 is the min
lw $s1,A
la $t2,E
subu $t5,$t2,$t1    # t5 to know the location of the last value and decreses it 

move $t6,$t1
move $t3,$t1        #adress of next value

srl $t4,$t5,2
addi $t7,$t4,0

outerloop:
#addiu $t1,$t1,4

x:
addiu $t3,$t3,4
lw $s2,0($t3)

bleu $s1,$s2,B
move $t6,$t3
lw $s6,0($t6)

subiu $t5,$t5,4
B: j x 

exit:
li $v0,10
syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define a size for the array and test the number of checked elements, OR define a final element of the array (such as a zero), and stop if you encounter that element.